# How to set NIC in promiscuous mode on mac book air?

Tags: macos, bash, network-adapter, ifconfig, tcpdump

With MacOSx, I am trying to run my nic in promiscuous mode and then use `tshark` / `tcpdump` to capture traffic.

### Option 1:

```
 ifconfig en0 promisc
```

but I get this message:

```
ifconfig: promisc: bad value
```

### Option 2:

I tried `sudo tcpdump -In -i en0 host 10.0.0.2` and it didn't work **too**. I followed: [tcpdump promiscuous mode on OSX 10.8](https://superuser.com/questions/541728/tcpdump-promiscuous-mode-on-osx-10-8) . `10.0.0.2` is my local host - and it prints nothing to bash:

```
tcpdump: listening on en0, link-type IEEE802_11_RADIO (802.11 plus radiotap header), capture size 65535 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
99 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Answer (score 2):

TShark and tcpdump will put the interface into promiscuous mode unless you tell them *NOT* to do so with the `-p` flag - `-p` doesn't mean "promiscuous mode", it means "not promiscuous mode".

`-I` turns on *monitor* mode.

Note that if you're on a "protected" network using encryption, i.e. a network using WEP or WPA/WPA2, capture filters other than at the link layer won't work, because the packets being handed to the packet capture mechanism (BPF, in the case of OS X) do *not* have the payload decrypted.  This means a filter such as "host 10.0.0.2" won't work.

Comment: what do you mean by `BPF do not have the payload decrypted` the key is identical to all the hosts in the network.

Comment: I mean that the OS will not decrypt the packets before handing it to the code that implements filters, even though it will decrypt packets *sent to the host* (but not packets sent to some other host) before handing them to *the networking stack*.  Therefore, any filter expression that looks at the IP layer, such as "host 10.0.0.2", will fail.

Comment: So how can I sniff the packets ?

Comment: If you're on a WEP or WPA/WPA2 network: don't use a capture filter, make sure you capture the initial EAPOL handshakes for all hosts you care about if it's a WPA/WPA2 network, and [follow these directions in Wireshark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11) (or manually add the keys to your Wireshark preferences file if you can only use TShark).